# Add rows to variable to create a table - RStudio

Tags: r, dataframe, datatable, rows

I'm trying to do a correlation matrix between stocks on RStudio. Each stock has some empty (NA) data in some dates and starts the time series on a different date. Before creating the matrix, I need to create a table (with data.frame or another option) with all the variables (stock prices), but it is not possible because each one has a different amount of rows. There are two possible answers:
1) How can I add NA data to all the variables that have missing rows in a way to create the table? or;
2) How can I only keep the rows that have data for all the variables that I need for the correlation matrix?

Comment: It would help if you provided a reprex: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/. You might want to look into the `na.omit` function, to remove all NA data from your dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides an answer to 1):

**ILLUSTRATIVE DATA**:

```
set.seed(123)
stock1 <- sample(50:100, 10)
stock2 <- sample(50:100, 5)
```

**SOLUTION**:

To tailor the dataframe variables to the same length, you can take the length of the longest vector, `stock1` in the illustrative data above, as a reference point, substract the length of the other vectors from it to obtain the number of necessary `NA`. You can concatenate the shorter vectors plus that number of `NA` rows using `rep`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Stock_1 = stock1,
  Stock_2 = c(stock2, rep(NA, length(stock1) - length(stock2)))
)
```

**RESULT**:

```
df
   Stock_1 Stock_2
1       64      98
2       89      72
3       70      83
4       92      77
5       94      54
6       52      NA
7       73      NA
8       99      NA
9       96      NA
10      69      NA
```